# How to get 24V from this transformer

Tags: electrical, transformer

I'm confused - the arrows in this picture of a doorbell transformer range from 8V - 24V with arrows pointing just about everywhere.

I think I need to buy this to get enough power to a Nest doorbell. If I install this, how do I get 24V instead of 8V for example.

[image: Heath Zenith SL-125-02 Wired Door Chime Transformer]

Image: Heath Zenith SL-125-02 Wired Door Chime Transformer

Comment: Right and left for 24.  Right and Centre for 16.  Left and Centre for 8.

Comment: What does the nest doorbell call for?  How many volts/amps and AC or DC power.  Check before buying.

Comment: Crip clarified. I get how this works now.

Comment: The Nest doorbell is some kind of smart device? Is it ok with getting unregulated AC? Normally you wouldn't buy a naked transformer, you would buy a power supply.

Comment: My current doorbell is wired into a 10V transformer. The wired Nest doorbell will require 16V-24V. The power and voltage requirements for the Nest doorbell can be found here: https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/9247132?hl=en

Comment: The wires on the other side are to be connected to the house voltage.  Select from the screws you see there for the voltage you want.

Comment: @AndreKR for computer kit, yes, but smart doorbells are meant to be drop-in replacements for dumb mechanical ones so it would make sense for them to internally rectify and regulate

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The arrows point to the screws that will give a specific voltage and amps.

For 24 volts at 20VA you use the right and left screws. Centre screw is left empty/unused.

For 16 volts at 10VA you use the right and centre screws.

For 8 volts at 10VA you use the left and centre screws.

Comment: Additionally, this can be tested using a common digital multimeter, an exceptionally useful tool for specific tasks like this.  Strongly recommend adding a cheap $10-$20 meter to one's toolkit.

Comment: Unloaded the voltage is likely to read a little high, but that shouldn't be a problem.  For the Nest, if you're worried, you could use the 16V pair as that's also within spec